# Attempting to setup Ubuntu 12.04 SSH Server: -bash: /etc/hostname: Permission denied

Tags: command-line, server, bash, permissions, ssh

Attempting to setup an SSH-server running Ubuntu 12.04. Went to "HowToForge" to scout for potentially advanced or knowledgeable advice upon how to accomplish this, then I ended up running into a problem; off of one of their "Perfect Server Setup" how-to's, naturally taking advantage the distro mentioned above. Regardless, I am hitting a point where the instructions want me to *echo* the following command to */etc/hostname*:

```
echo server1.example.com > /etc/hostname
```

...then the following error is thrown:

```
-bash: /etc/hostname: Permission denied
```

Great, don't know why, I should have *administrative privileges*. Then I tried to see whether */etc/hostname* is writable via *lsattr*, and I get:

```
-------------e- /etc/hostname
```

Last time I checked, this implied that my file was not immutable.

In either case, what is happening, and what am I doing wrong? Want to setup a "secure" server, and all I read are a bunch of snarky comments online that grant little to no assistance for my needs; or anyone else's for that matter. Too many elitist mentalities bouncing around I guess. In either case, I would absolutely appreciate it if anybody could shed some light on this dilemma. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For scripting purpose, you could use tee to have the administrator rights to write the file:

```
echo server1.example.com | sudo tee /etc/hostname > /dev/null 2>&1
```

Answer (score 4):

You'll need administrative privileges to edit a file which is not owned by you. To execute the command `echo server1.example.com > /etc/hostname`, you will have to do the following:

```
sudo -i
```

enter your password if you are the administrator or if you are not, ask the administrator to enter the password

and then

```
echo server1.example.com > /etc/hostname
```

Comment: Yes, this works perfectly. In addition, thanks for the lead concerning sudoers, and how it effects environmental variables. Thanks!

Answer (score -3):

Try:

```
sudo echo server1.example.com > /etc/hostname
```

Comment: This would give the same results since the redirection takes place before you get superuser privileges.